# Insert and update query is excuted at time when using session.flush() in hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate annotation, when i used session.flush, insert and update query is executed at the same time..

```
ChequeTr chequeTr = new ChequeTr();
chequeTr.setPrnNo("1234561452");
 .
 .//more values set
 .

chequeTr.setContNo("25874123");
session.save(chequeTr);
session.flush();
trans.commit();
```

Hibernate:

```
insert into CHEQUE_TR_NEW (AWB_NO, BRANCH_CODE, UNIQUE_ID, CONT_NO,  
  CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, DISPATCH_DATE, DISPATCH_MODE, DISPATCH_TYPE,  
  PRN_NO, RECEIVED_BY, RELATIONSHIP_MOBILE, REMARKS, RTO_REASON_CODE,  
  STAGE_DATE, STAGE, STAGE_REV_REMARKS, CHEQUE_TR_ID) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Hibernate:

```
update CHEQUE_TR_NEW  
set AWB_NO=?, BRANCH_CODE=?, UNIQUE_ID=?, CONT_NO=?,  
  CREATED_BY=?, CREATED_ON=?, DISPATCH_DATE=?, DISPATCH_MODE=?,  
  DISPATCH_TYPE=?, PRN_NO=?, RECEIVED_BY=?, RELATIONSHIP_MOBILE=?,  
  REMARKS=?, RTO_REASON_CODE=?, STAGE_DATE=?, STAGE=?, STAGE_REV_REMARKS=?  
where CHEQUE_TR_ID=?
```

Can any body guide me on this?

Comment: Is it the problem for you? What do you expect?

Comment: I agree that I would have expected it to do it once. Has the session flush mode been changed?

Comment: I want to understand this concept.. If I am using session.save() then logically only insert query will execute..  but why update query?  this is impacting on performance..